# windows.h setpixel isnt working in project

Tags: c++

I am writing some code to get acquainted with the windows API. I was able to get a window to open but when I tried to write a program to draw random pixels. I am using GCC with Vscode. here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void DrawPixels(HWND hwnd);

int WINAPI 
WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {

    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Pixels";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Pixels",
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                100, 100, 300, 250, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch(msg) {

        case WM_PAINT:

            DrawPixels(hwnd);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:

            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void DrawPixels(HWND hwnd) {

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT r;

    GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);

    if (r.bottom == 0) {
    
        return;
    }

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {

        int x = rand() % r.right;
        int y = rand() % r.bottom;
        SetPixel(hdc, x, y, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    }

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
```

Whenever I try to compile this I get the error main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x224): undefined reference to `SetPixel@16'

I have tried changing the variables and the types but it isnt working.

Comment: Your title isn't correct - it's not that any function isn't working, you can't even build the executable. This means the code you shared doesn't really matter. What matters is which libraries you link against, and whether they contain the missing symbol. Sadly, your not sharing the full linker or compiler invocation here

Comment: try adding -lgdi32 to the compiler options